# While doing migration using flask_migrate, .db file is generated after running flask db migrate -m "user" but table is not created?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a user table using flask_sqlalchemy  and trying to migrate using flask_migrate. But no user table is created .
.db file has been generated in project directory but in migration/version no version has been generated.
How to resolve this issue ?

I followed these articles , but I did not find the solution . Here are the articles :-
https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app,db)
from app import routes
```

I got this output on my Terminal 
flask db migrate -m 'users'

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected.

and expected output was :
(venv) $ flask db migrate -m "users table"
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'user'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_user_email' on '['email']'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index 'ix_user_username' on '['username']'
  Generating /home/miguel/microblog/migrations/versions/e517276bb1c2_users_table.py ... done
```

Comment: The output says that `No changes in schema detected.`. In the  snippet of your code that you have shared, you have not imported models describing database structure for your application. You have to follow through the tutorial and eyeball the code differences between your code and the one there and you'll find how to correct it.

Comment: Thank You Oluwafemi Sule for your help.After importing models.py ,when I run my application and try to insert data in registration form , It gives an error saying ''' No such table : user '''.

Comment: After importing `models`, you need to run `flask db migrate -m "some comment about the migration"` to update your database structure to the declared schema in  `models`. This should create the tables.\

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. If you look at the import statement on the bottom of __init__.py, you didn't add the 'models' module, so it doesn't know about the new data model you created.

This is what __init__.py should look like at this point in the tutorial:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Config


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```